# Validation of php mail script

Tags: php, regex, sendmail, spam

So I have this script that I use for all my emails in different domains. For some reasons, the second I started using it on a 1&1 hosting account - I've been getting tons of spam! **A condition that stops emails without a sender doesn't work** - some of the spam comes from fake spam emails.

Here is the script:

```
<?php
$nambre = $_POST['name'];
$number = $_POST['number'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$user_message = $_POST['message'];
$message = "<h3>From:&nbsp;".$nambre."</h1>";
$message .= "<h3>Phone:&nbsp;".$number."</h3><br/>";
$message .=$user_message;
$headers = "From: " . strip_tags($_POST['email']) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags($_POST['email']) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
mail ( 'email@email.com' , 'Someone is contacting you from you website',        $message, $headers );
header("location: success.html");
?>
```

Is there anything I can do?

Comment: Add a Captcha to your form, perhaps?

Comment: Look into the honeypot method.

Comment: Another good way to get spam is by providing your email in plain text on StackOverflow

Comment: who be stupid enough to do that...

Comment: For one thing, remove the dot in your first `$message .= "<h3>From:&nbsp;".$nambre."</h1>";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need a captcha or some other type of human-validation. I would suggest that you time the page-load to form-submission. Since bots will do it automatically and therefore in  a matter of milliseconds, it would be easy to do it with Javascript's `Date()` object.

`<joke>`

Alternatively, you could ask the bot/human what `.1+.2` is, and if the result comes out to `0.30000000000000004`, you've got a bot.

`</joke>`

If you're looking more specifically for a CAPTCHA based one, you could use [reCAPTCHA](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/php).

However, another interesting thing that I have seen work well is to have a form field that is either hidden or has a message to the user saying not to fill it in. If the user fills it in, you can be confident that your script will reject both bots and humans who don't know how to read

Comment: That's an interesting idea.

Comment: Use your servers time, not client time. Using the latter is asking for trouble because you can't control the client time.

Comment: If I were to add a small input under the form with a placeholder that reads "whats 2+2" and validate it using a php condition would that work? Can a bot figure that out?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using math, I wasn't serious when I said that. I would use one of the other methods

Comment: Bots are exactly that: robotic.  They are generalized and focused on spamming thousdands of sites.  They have no particular interest in yours specifically, so anything on the form that deviates from the norm is highly effective in my experience.  Something like: "What is two plus two"  will just about kill all spam from bots.  You could easily vary this with a few different questions if you wanted to be extra careful, but the bot writers don't have much interest in doing something custom just to get one spam email into your inbox.